# Is it possible to define a constructor taking a universal reference with defaulted value?

Tags: c++, forwarding-reference

When I try to define a constructor taking a universal reference with a defaulted value as a parameter like this:

```cpp
struct S {
    int x; // I know that universal ref is useless for int, but it's here for simplicity

    template<class T>
    S(const T&& arg = 123) : x(std::forward(arg)) { }
    
    // S(const auto&& arg = 123) : x(std::forward(arg)) { }
    // The auto-syntax fails as well, yields similar error
};

int main() {
    S s;
}
```

I get an error:

```
<source>:18:7: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'S'
    S s;
      ^
<source>:10:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    S(const T&& arg = 123) : x(std::forward(arg)) { }
    ^
<source>:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
struct S {
       ^
<source>:3:8: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: requires 1 argument, but 0 were provided
```

Is there a way to do it with a universal reference or do I have to do it in a different way?

Comment: just write a default constructor

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a forwarding reference. [Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) says `const T &&` doesn't do, it has to be `T &&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to specify a default argument for the template parameter. It will not be deduced from the function parameter's default argument:

```
template<class T = int>
```

You also are misusing `std::forward`. It always requires a type template argument that should be the template parameter used in the forwarding reference named by the argument.

```
 x(std::forward<T>(arg))
```

And finally, a `const` rvalue reference almost never makes sense. In particular it doesn't form a forwarding reference. Remove the `const`:

```
S(T&& arg = 123)
```

Then it should compile. But just declaring an additional overload without parameters might be simpler.

---

Note: In the above *forwarding reference* is synonymous with what the question refers to as *universal reference*. The former is the now technically correct term used in the standard. The latter is older and was popularized in writing before there was an official term.

Answer (score 1):

`T` is not deduced from default argument, you might default it too:

```
template<class T = int>
S(T&& arg = 123) : x(std::forward<T>(arg)) {}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PvhGE8cGh)

Comment: That forward doesn't work. `const`-qualified rvalue references to template parameters do not count as forwarding references.

Comment: @user17732522: `const T&&` is rarely what we want, but it might still useful in some rare cases. but indeed remove it is probably more what OP wants.

Comment: The problem is that it will never deduce to an lvalue reference, so the `forward` would be pointless.